# Handheld amateur radio

Tags: united-states, hf, vhf

Recently purchased a MY-EMR1 which is a handheld ham radio and I want to synchronize it to my sisters in another state if it is possible, she has the same type of radio. All the frequencies have been put in both, mine for Las Vegas, NV and hers for Golden Valley/Kingman, AZ. Or is their something else that needs to be done to be able to contact each other in a "REAL EMERGENCY" a.k.a power grid failure or whatever else that could happen.

Comment: That should all be part of your ham exam preparation, without which you're not allowed to use ham radio frequencies. Of course, in a "real emergency", nobody will sue you for arranging for life-saving help. How is a power grid failure a "real emergency", in which life and death are at stake? Sounds like an extended inconvenience with worst case property damage (thawed food), nothing for which you would be allowed to ignore the law that governs access to spectrum? This would be different if the lack of electricity would actually e.g. shut down critical life-support systems (dialysis pumps, etc)

Comment: But then I'm really not sure how you're going to help from states away. Your sister would be best served with an emergency button of the local health services then, and these know when there's a large outage.

Comment: You'll need to clarify your question quite considerably; what sort of "REAL EMERGENCY" do you mean? What license classes do you and your sister hold? What frequencies do you mean by "al the frequencies"?

It would also help to know a bit about the radio - while I can probably look it up, knowing that it's a HF unit, or 2m/70cm handheld, or 1.25m handheld, and what power levels it can operate at would be helpful. As would knowing what antennas you've put up, and what you're able to put up.

Answer (score 3):

A little research on the MY-EMR1 radio finds that it is a rebranded UHF/VHF radio (probably also with boosted price) marketed to preppers, likely with poor or incorrect documentation and a high price.   It is not legal to use this radio without a proper license.   While the relevant laws hint it might be legal to use these radios in some emergencies, any emergency sufficiently severe to allow them to be used without a license would be bad enough these radios would not work for a distance greater than 3-5 miles

Assuming both parties have a license, in ideal conditions with a repeater in the correct location, they might work at a distance of 50-100 miles, so you would both basically have be very near the border between NV/AZ for this to be useful, and that's assuming someone has already set up a repeater in a favorable location between you.

If you are further than that, you would likely need a linked repeater system which likely uses internet, which likely would fail in an emergency.

Ideally, you would each get an amateur radio license and study the material about propagation and repeaters carefully, and possibly get a general license, which allows you to use HF radios (rather than VHF/UHF) which in some conditions can go up to 150 miles, or further than 400 miles.  However, this needs a complicated setup with large antennas and a different radio.

Note that devices like this require a lot of knowledge and skill to use successfully (and safely), and you need to practice using them in non-emergency conditions (which requires a license).  If you do not use them except in an emergency, you will find that when the emergency occurs, you will not be able to get them to work.  If you've studied the material and practiced using them, then in an emergency you will have tried and will know exactly what does and doesn't work and *when* and what you have to to do to get it working.